# Getting nvidia Optimus to work with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, nvidia-optimus

I have recently upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 16.04. I'm using a hp pavilion 17 laptop with a GeForce GT 740M graphics card. The Optimus technology caused all kinds of trouble on 14.04, and I never got the proprietary drivers to run properly. Right now, I'm using nouveau which kind of works, as long as I deactivate hardware acceleration / deinterlacing in Totem and Firefox (if I don't, I get terrible screen tearing). In 14.04, I also tried to run Bumblebee, which did not work either. Is anything known about the situation for 16.04? Is there any hope of something working that did not work in 14.04?